# Hot reload changes not showing in Android emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am running Visual Studio 2019 16.5.3 and using Xamarin forms 4.4.0.9 and can't get hot reload to work for android. I have Linking set to none. Is there any tricks I should know to get this working ? Maybe I am not standing on the right foot ?

[image: is this what you are talking about with no link ?]

[image]

It is enabled and I believe it was enabled by default

### Things I have tried

- App source is in c:\dev\project (to provide a short path)
- uninstall the app from the VM and rerun the app in VS (reinstalled the app)
- delete the android VM and recreate a new one
- delete all android VM's and recreate a new one
- restart VS
- restart computer
- delete bin folder and obj folder of all 3 projects and rebuilt
- made sure enable hot reload for Xamarin.forms is checked (see
  picture)
- made sure linker properties is set to none (see picture)
- create a new project and start from scratch (this duplicated controls in the app on hot reload) (this project has 6 views)

  - loaded another small project (two views) and it worked so maybe this is project specific

Comment: just uninstall build and re-run project make sure that hot reloading is enabled.

Comment: So it just started working I haven't changed anything ... werid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this has something to do with the android project itself.

```
1. Created Xamarin Forms Project with the same name
2. Backed up my version old android project and moved it to another folder (the one that was not working correctly)
3. copied over the new android project I created into the solution
4. did a diff between the two projects and figured out what was different 
5. Copied over what changes I had made to the new android project
```

After this everything works smoothly as far as the hot refresh now.

Comment: What were the differences? Can you tell?

Comment: You haven't explained the crucial bit - what the difference was which was causing the problem.

Comment: I didn't get to dig that far into the problem I just know what worked sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your linker settings are set to "Don't Link"

Comment: where are these linker settings in the android project ?

Comment: See picture above

Comment: Have you enabled it via Tools - Options - > Xamarin -> Hot Reload?